# Most efficient passing of a temporary string literal in C++17?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-literals, string-view

I did try and look elsewhere but couldn't find a full answer.

So lets say I have a function or class constructor that creates a window, the function is most likely to be called with a string literal:
`auto myWindow = CreateWindow("Window Title");`

I was wondering what would be the best way to write the function/constructor declaration as there seems to be many options such as a const string ref, a string_view or a C style string literal. I also wondered if an rvalue string might be better than a ref as it could be moved and therefore constructed in the function stack. I would like the CreateWindow function to be an interface to or wrapper around an  API such as Qt, SDL or directly with the OS so the string literal will likely be passed onto another function anyway so it might get converted to the appropriate type for that function. This question is mainly educational for me as it has very little impact on this example I was just wondering if anyone could give some insight generally into string literal passing in modern C++ with all the options it's a bit confusing for me!

I hope I'm following the stack overflow decorum properly if not please forgive me it's my first time lol!

```
class Window
{
public:
    Window(const int Width, const int Height, STRING_LITERAL Title);
    virtual ~Window();
    Window(const Window& copy) = delete;
    Window& operator=(const Window& assign) = delete;
};
```

Comment: What are you going to be doing with the string in the constructor?

Comment: Do you need to save (copy) the string? Will the string be passed on to somewhere else? Will it *always* be a *literal* string, i.e. there's no chance someone will want to pass a `std::string` object?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on how you're going to store the title in the Window class. It will generally be most efficient to pass (possibly a reference to) the same type of thing you're going to store, since you'll avoid any kind of conversion in the event that the caller has the type you need. If you're doing your own conversion then you'll add the cost of that on top of whatever conversion is needed to get the caller's type to conform to your constructor.

Comment: You've added a little detail, but honestly the answer depends _completely_ on exactly what your constraints are, so you're going to have to find those out and tell us before we can give you an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no good-for-all-cases string class in the standard library for parameter passing. So the answer depends on the intended usage.

Comment: It would most likely be passed onto another function but the function signature could be string_view or C style string or const str ref depending on the API used.. would it be right to say I should take it as a forwarding reference and just forward it on as a template parameter??

Comment: Okay first situation: if the function simply uses the literal as an arg to a function taking a C style string. Second situation is the arg must be passed onto a function of an unknown API so the type must fit most general cases such as the ones mentioned?

Comment: In the title you say "temporary string", but in the text, you don't use a temporary. Which is intended? Or both?

Comment: So I'd imagine that a C style string will convert to most things however I have seen some comments saying that string_view should be used in modern C++ ( probably for the reason that there is a few different options of using string literals and string_view is pretty bare bones like a C style string ) What's people's opinion on the better general case? I don't need to store it or make any copies in my Window class however the windowing API likely will.

Comment: Each has its pros/cons. `string_view` is bad, when a temporary string is passed, and the passed string is intended to be stored (because it will create a new string, instead of moving). And a `string_view` may not have a terminating zero.

Comment: Okay that's useful to know, I think I may have to do some experimenting and more research then to see which option is going to be more flexible but also which avoids unnecessary copies. Still learning but I have to say it seems like there are too many options for passing strings in C++ XD. I suppose each one fits a very specific function though. Like I said it shouldn't have much perf impact in this example anyway, I just wondered if there was a general way more preferred in modern C++ but seems like there is no one method that fits all cases. Thanks for your responses tho! :)